# OK to comment pointing people to emacs.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

The title says it really, but I'll elaborate a bit:

There are a fair number of posts on SO (and also on SU) on emacs which appear to be more about using or configuring emacs than programming it.  That's fuzzy dividing line, but I guess either way the emacs site is appropriate.

Is it OK to point people towards emacs.stackexchange.com in comments?

I'm not actually 100% what is on topic for emacs SE, since this doesn't say, but I assume pretty much all things emacs are considered fair game there (both programming and using):

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Just make sure that the question isn't a cross-site dup.  That means either deletion or custom-flag migration (since it isn't in the default migration options).  Make them aware of this as well, and I wouldn't think there would be any problems.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Directing someone to a site where their question is off topic (or otherwise out of scope) is be *very* problematic.  That site will close the question, and the user will be all the more confused/upset for being given conflicting advice about what to do.

Comment: @Servy yeah I kinda just assumed that the referenced question was actually on-topic.  If there's doubt, then, like you answered, migration is a bad option.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wasn't asking about moving questions, just making people aware it exists.

Comment: Not sure why this is considered duplicate: the referenced question appears to be about off-topic questions, but certainly many emacs questions are considered on topic here (but also no doubt on topic on the emacs site -- see http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/274/guidance-re-what-is-on-topic-here).

Comment: Your first introduction to a site is the tour page (`/tour`, “Tour” in the help menu; a redesign of the old-timey /about page). That starts with a one-sentence description of the site.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not actually 100% what is on topic for emacs SE

That's a pretty compelling reason to not direct users to it then.  You should only be directing users to another site if you're extremely confident that the question is on topic on that site.

In my (granted, somewhat limited) experiences, the vast majority of site's have a scope more narrow than people expect after only reading the name of the site.

Comment: How about we generously assume this question gets answered as best it can and I follow that advice?  http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/274/guidance-re-what-is-on-topic-here

Comment: @CroadLangshan That works out fine when your assumption is correct.  It works out terribly whenever your assumption is incorrect.  Users directing questions to sites where they don't belong (even if they appear to belong to an outside) has historically been a major problem for SE.